# JOOQ With Oracle19c: DSL Correct Oracle Version

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jooq, oracle19c

I am using JOOQ With Oracle 19. In running a Simple query with DSLContext, Should I use Oracle or Oracle18C? Both of them seem to work, just curious

```
 DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.ORACLE);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SQLDialect` class models two things in one:

#### Dialect families

[`SQLDialect.ORACLE`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#ORACLE) is the dialect family for the Oracle Database. It is very distinct from e.g. the `SQLDialect.MYSQL` dialect family.

It can also be used as a SQL dialect, in case of which it always corresponds to the *latest* currently supported SQL dialect. In case of jOOQ 3.15, that would be `SQLDialect.ORACLE21C`, so the behaviour of `ORACLE` and `ORACLE21C` is the same.

As soon as a hypothetical Oracle 23c is released, and jOOQ once jOOQ supports it, the family `ORACLE` will correspond to the dialect `ORACLE23C`.

#### Dialects

The versioned SQL dialects in jOOQ correspond to their respective Oracle Database versions. For best results on Oracle 19c, use `SQLDialect.ORACLE18C`. No `ORACLE19C` dialect has been added, as jOOQ didn't yet add any 19c specific feature support.

This dialect will continue to work on Oracle 18c (and 19c) as it is the one used to integration test jOOQ on these Oracle versions. Even if Oracle decides to support the standard SQL `BOOLEAN` type in 23c, for example (one can hope), then `SQLDialect.ORACLE18C` will continue to emulate the type, whereas a new `SQLDialect.ORACLE23C` (and the `SQLDialect.ORACLE` dialect family) will generate boolean value expressions.